# 7-Zip throws an error in SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis, 7zip

I have the following problem:

I use 7-Zip in my SSIS 2012 package.

So I created the Execute Process task and put there:

**WorkingDirectory**: `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\` (it's correct, double checked it)

**Executable**: `7z.exe`

**Argumnets**: `e "C:\Data\B1\Arch.7z" -so > "C:\Data\B1\Arch.7z.dat"`

It means that I want to put all unzipped data to the file (stdout) Arch.7z.dat.

When I run the package I got the following error:
**Cannot use absolute pathnames for this command**
This error is thrown by 7-Zip.

But when I run the same command from command line it work correctly:

`C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z.exe e "C:\Data\B1\Arch.7z" -so > "C:\Data\B1\Arch.7z.dat"`

What is the problem there?

Thanks
Mik

Comment: What do you mean by unzipping the data to stdout? Can you not extract them to a folder and then do a for each ennumerator to go through the files?

Comment: In the .7z file there is one file. but extension of this file may be various (.dat or .txt or .tsv). So when I would use -so switch, I was sure what would be extracted file name. just by adding to the .dat extension.

Comment: It may be odd as it sounds, but try with 2 files or more in the Arch.7z as &-zip is picky sometimes, when there is only 1 file in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

The -o switch specifies the output folder and has to be used in addition to specifying the path in the -so switch. Specifying only the -o switch without the full path in the -so redirect or only the full path in the redirect without the -o switch won't work as expected or at all.

It should look like this:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z.exe e -oC:\Data\B1 C:\Data\B1\Arch.7z -so > C:\Data\B1\Arch.7z.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something as follows.

```
Executable  C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
Arguments   e “C:\Data\B1\Arch.7z”
Working directory   <Path of your source file>
```

Take a look at the following example.

[Example to Unzip using 7 Zip in SSIS](http://gowdhamand.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/extracting-zip-files-using-ssis/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. It worked for me earlier with the parmas that I provided in my post but using -o switch. The problem is that -so switch throws the error. Now using params you provided it throws another error when I put -so switch - "No files to process"...